# Affine matrix transformation

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, affinetransform

I have two images one is input image([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuAM2.jpg)) and other is output image ([enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5RIl.jpg)). Output image is produced using some function on input image using the affine transformation. I need to find the function using 3 tie points on the input image and then corresponding points on the output image.

As affine matrix has the following equations

```
 x = v * t11 + w * t21 + t31;

 y = v * t12 + w * t22 + t32;
```

Now after applying some calculations I found the values of all unknown variables `i,e t11,t21 etc.`. Now I want to apply these values on the input images to make it like output image.

Here is the code in C#.

```
            for(int i=0; i<file1.Width; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<file1.Height; j++)
            {
                x = i * t11 + j * t21 + t31;

                y = i * t12 + j * t22 + t32;

                 file1.SetPixel(i,j , );

            }
```

but I cannot figure out that how to distort image 2 on image 1 to get the results though i have all the values i need. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is it you don't know? just pasting a few lines of code and saying you don't know what to do won't give you any good answers. describe what you do step by step, add code where it makes sense and then explain what exaclty it is you don't know

Comment: An affine transform is a matrix that is applied to transform coordinates in one image into the image space of the other. Sounds like you've calculated the the values to fill the matrix, correct? What step can't you figure out how to do, apply the matrix to each pixel in the original image?

Comment: @JayT yes you r right that is my probmel

Comment: @JayT I don't know how to use these values to form a pixle value to insert into the original image

Comment: It should be just a simple matrix multiplication, i.e. multiply each pixel in the source image by the determined matrix to find it's location in the new image space. However, this isn't necessarily trivial because often the output pixel coordinates are not at integer values, rather they fall between pixels. In that case you need to interpolate the value. There are libraries that calculate and apply transforms out there, I have used [ITK](http://www.itk.org/) which has a [C# wrapper](http://www.simpleitk.org/) available.